# Turn the code into a code using SIMD instructions

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, simd

I am preparing for an exam and are doing some exercises without facit. So I am been giving this code and are wondering if I have turned the code into SIMD instructions.

**The code**

```
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

for int(i=0; i < 100000; i++)
    C += A[i] * B[i];
```

Since there is no remainder, we don't need to take care of it. We also assume that it is a 128 bit register, and therefore can calculate 4 single precision floating point values.

**My result - using SIMD**

```
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

for int(i=0; i < 100000/4; i += 4)
    C += A[i] * B[i];
    C += A[i+1] * B[i+1];
    C += A[i+2] * B[i+2];
    C += A[i+3] * B[i+3];
```

What advantages can you see for using SIMD instructions instead of writing programs with multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the omitted curly braces on your second loop is simply a typo, and typo in the for loop, and the fact that you ask about multiplying floats but your code shows arrays of ints, this won't get great vectorisation even if the compiler sees it. While the compiler might do the loads of 4 values from A and B as a single instruction each, and do the 4 multiplies in one instruction, your code forces the compiler to then extract each of the 4 products and sum them sequentially, and getting individual values out of a SIMD register is typically quite slow.

If on the other hand you did this

```
float A[100000];
float B[100000];
float C0=0, C1=0, C2=0, C3=0;

for (size_t i=0; i < 100000/4; i += 4)
{
    C0 += A[i+0] * B[i+0];
    C1 += A[i+1] * B[i+1];
    C2 += A[i+2] * B[i+2];
    C3 += A[i+3] * B[i+3];
}
float C = (C0 + C1) + (C2 + C3);
```

Then a good compiler could vectorise this as now it sees that within each loop it loads two SIMD registers, multiplies them, then it can add the result to a SIMD register of the sums, and only extracts those 4 sums and sums them all at the end.

A vectorising compile can do this with SIMD and it will not change the order of evaluation of individual sums (FP maths is NOT associative). The compiler is typically not allowed to change the order of FP maths for this reason (not without some extra flags that allow it to technically breach the language standards), so the code above can be precisely represented by SIMD instructions, and will run much faster (in fact I'd unwind the loop a further stage as the multiplication will be a bottleneck as it stands).

This is sort of the trick with SIMD, you have to understand and then think how the operation would be best implemented with vector instructions, and then write your code to execute the same sequence of operations, and hope the compiler spots what you've done.

Or you can write the vector instructions yourself with intrinsics, or use OpenMP or similar to tell the compiler more explicitly what to do.

Amongst the advantages of SIMD over threads for such an operation is the fact that you're making use of more of the silicon within a single core... so you're not preventing another thread from getting cycles. On our compute grid we typically run many single threaded processes on any one machine to keep all the cores busy at all times... in such a case doing this sum using more cores is a false economy, you'd simply be stealing cycles that another thread could usefully be running another job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the provided code should compile into SIMD instructions with capable CPUs and compilers.

On vector-capable processors, SIMD exposes hardware features that greatly accelerate identical, parallel computations.  For instance, SIMD typically makes better use of the cache on a single core due to streaming RAM access, assuming the data being processed is localized in contiguous areas of memory.  Using multiprocessing, cache competition and other synchronization overhead could actually reduce performance as the various cores attempt to write data simultaneously.  This is in addition to the intrinsic boost on von-Neumann machines from only having to read one, not four, separate instructions from the shared system memory.

The logic to do these arithmetic operations in parallel is always present, but requires specific SIMD instructions to utilize.  As a result, SIMD tends to be used in hot loops where hand tuning makes overall optimization sense.

Comment: Well, a vectorizing optimizer may or many not optimize either loop but in an exam environment I would expect to see a more explicit mapping onto the underlying architecture to clarify that the student has understood the principles of the system. In particular the horizontal addition should be performed as a vector addition with final folding at the end, especially since the equivalent floating-point case is likely forbidden due to the lack of associativity. Explicit alignment specifications for the arrays couldn't hurt either to avoid wind-up code complexity from deterring the optimizer.

Comment: For an exam I'd prefer to see this hand-coded in assembly for the target architecture, to be honest.  Given a halfway decent compiler though this code should end up being optimized (did some similar vector stuff for HPC in the past and verified assembly output from GCC).  OP should definitely disassembly the binaries and check for SIMD instructions...

Comment: Agreed, intrinsics would be the way to go here and optimizing compilers can do wonders with tangled code (and conversely randomly break down for obscure reasons). What mostly bothers me here is the mention of `single precision floating point values` for which case, that is substituting `int` for `float`, were are left with an inherently serial dependency chain for the accumulation unless using scary options like `-ffast-math` and breaking most numeric algorithms in the process. Honestly, I can't see the answer being accepted in an examination unless a parallel accumulation buffer was used.